# Java - Possible main method arguments in windows

Tags: java, windows, file, startup, main-method

I wondered whether there was any connection between the main method's parameter `String[] args` and the possibility of opening files with a specified program.
Considering that I wrote a simple program that writes down every String of `args`, then opened some files with this program (I am using windows).
This is what happened:
No matter what kind of file I opened with my program (right click -> open with...), `args`contained only one String which was the file's complete path.
When I ran the program on itself, `args` was of length 0.

Now my question is: are there **any other Strings** that might be contained in `args` or would the following code always work without doubt?
(I want to use this on windows, not play around with it like `java MyProgram 1 2 3 "test"`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    initProgram();

    if (args.length != 0) {            //file opened with program
        loadFile(new File(args[0]));
    }
}
```

Thank you for your answers and please be patient with my english.

Comment: You will only receive one argument while opening one file, tryed to drag two files on top of a Jar file to see if it receives many?

Comment: If you try to start many files at once (not a list as argument) windows will start a new instance of the program for each, you should look if you can listen for a second file on the same proccess (like GIMP does for many files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Marcos Vasconcelos assumed: by opening multiple files at once `args` will contain **all the files' paths** tried to open, so `args` can be larger than just one String. Its length depends on the amount of files that want to be opened with the program.